# How to design Users, Roles and permission schema?

Tags: database, permissions, user-roles

This is a very common thing in the web application developmet. I have done it number of times.

But I am stuck in my current project designing the schema for this.

The thing is my application will have three types of users in the begining e.g. SuperAdmin, Admin and the normal user.

I plan to have these user types as the roles like ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER.

The system can have many roles. In fact SuperAdmin and Admins an  create roles and assign those roles to users.

The problem is,

Super Admins will have permisson p1, p2 and p3. 
Super Admins can create other super admins. 
Super Admins can create admins.
Super Admins will not add users in the system.

Admins can have permissions p5,p6 and p7.
Admins can not create another admins. 
Admins can create other users.
Admins can also create roles like say Report viewers.

Super admin with permission p1, p2 and p3 should be able to create Admins with permissions p5, p6 and p7. Which I am not quite getting.

Logically when Super admmins themselves do not have permission p5, p6 and p7, how can they create admins with these permissions?

Please help me out with the proper design with this.

Below is the design I have so far.

USER
UserID  RoleID

ROLE
RoleID  RoleName

PERMISSION
PermissionID    PermissionName

ROLE_PERMISSION
 RoleID PermissionID

Thanks.

Comment: No comments yet. I thought this was very common thing in the web application developemnt. Someone must have come across such situation in the past. Please help.

Comment: This is really disappointing. Most of the questions that you ask on SO these days remain unanswered. Even after giving bounties. :(

Comment: hello ? someone please reply.

Comment: your question title will not attract any one :P, first read guidelines how to ask question

Comment: @Ravi. Okay, so I have edited my question title. But it did attract your attention. Never mind though :-) Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a loaded question, setting up members, roles, etc. is no small feat. I suggest you take a look at already written libraries to see if they may suit your needs. What you should start googling for, is 'Access Control Lists' (acl) for short.

Answer (score 3):

You should look into authorization frameworks and standards such as XACML - XACML lets you define authorization based on several attributes so that you don't end up in role explosion. So instead of creating a role manager_in_tx_with_gold_status, you can create rules e.g.:

> a user with role=manager and location=TX can do action=view on resources....

There are several vendor solutions and open source solutions too. Check out the Wikipedia page and the standard's homepage for more information:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML
- https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml

I have a Youtube channel too that talks about XACML:

- http://www.youtube.com/user/axiomaticsab?feature=watch

Answer (score 2):

Once designing a database like this;

I installed some forum, portal and CMS scripts and analyzed how they handled the situation, then extracted DB schemas and used them as a reference.

May be this can help